# Jquery validation with angular js(ng-view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

form page of ng-view

```
<form j-validate>
    <div class="msg">Sign in to start your session</div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
        </span>
        <div class="form-line">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="details.email" required autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
        </span>
        <div class="form-line">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="details.password" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 p-t-5">
            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme" class="filled-in chk-col-pink">
            <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-block bg-pink waves-effect" type="submit">SIGN IN</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-15 m-b--20">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 align-right">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/forgot_password">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

index-page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url()."assets/images/favicon.ico"; ?>" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/materialicons.css'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/angular/angular.min.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/angular/angular-route.min.js'); ?>"></script>
</head>
<body class="login-page">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

route js file

```
var app =  angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1/Public/CI_Module/Admin/hello',
            controller: 'AdminController'
        })
}]);
app.directive('jValidate', function() {
return {
link: function(scope, element, attr) {

  element.validate({

    rules: {
        'email': {
            required: true,
            email:true
        },
        'password': {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      console.log('Valid');
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
      console.log('InValid');
    }
  });

  scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  });
}
}
});
```

Now i want to add below code in angularjs so that i can show error texts with input text border highlight etc.

```
highlight: function (input) {
        console.log(input);
        $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.input-group').append(error);
    }
```

so please help me to combine jquery validation with angularjs. Thanks!!

Comment: You can use ng-class="'error':form.email.$invalid" at every .form-line node with respective child field

Comment: Yeah that's angular J's validation and I agree but I want jquery validation in angular js form submission with highlight, unhighlight and errorPacement.

Comment: See [Angular Validation](http://hueitan.github.io/angular-validation/).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.